# Is there a term similar to girlfriendship / boyfriendship?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sorry if this question is rather dumb.

Is "girlfriendship" or "boyfriendship" actually a term, or is there a suitable replacement?

I'm using "partnership" in the badly worded sentence right now:

> Even Equality's love interest, of whose partnership is a transgression
>   in its own

But is there something more accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word normally used is *relationship*.  It is usually clear enough from context that a romantic pairing is meant.  Substituting "relationship" for "partnership" in your example sentence doesn't seem to make it better, but I think that's because the sentence itself doesn't stand alone very well.  Show the entire paragraph and maybe we can give better advice.

I have never (before now) heard anyone say "girlfriendship" or "boyfriendship"; people would understand what you meant, but it would sound like you just made up the words on the spot.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this obvious one... Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Romance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/romance) would be a word that you are looking for, since it means

> Ardent emotional attachment or involvement between people; love.